# Get EXIF tags in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, exif

I would like to get all the EXIF tags of an image I took in Windows Phone 7. I have tried using ExifLib, but can't seem to get it right.

In my event handler for `CaptureImageAvailable` I have the following code:

```
JpegInfo info = ExifReader.ReadJpeg(e.ImageStream, "Pic.jpeg");
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
 {
      textBox1.Text = info.ExposureTime.ToString();
      textBox2.Text = info.FNumber.ToString();
                                });

e.ImageStream.Close();
```

Both `textBox1` and `textBox2` are displaying 0.

My "Cam.Capture event" is fired every 200 milliseconds. Does this have any effect on these values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: perhaps those tags do not exist in your image?

Comment: But it has to exist..since the pic is taken from the camera itself! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everything is ok with your code, the values just aren't set.

Here is evidence that it's not your fault:

- Have a look at [this blog post](https://igrali.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/reading-and-displaying-exif-photo-data-on-windows-phone/) which basically is a tutorial on reading EXIF data. There you find a screenshot of the data: many values are set but the ones you need are also 0. But I am not sure if this photo really was taken with the phone camera.
- So I tested myself and the values are as follows; the fields you need are 0 as well:

  ```
  Artist  ""
  Copyright   null
  DateTime    "2011:11:01 20:50:07"
  Description null
  ExposureTime    0.0
  FileName    "\\Applications\\Data\\[GUID]\\Data\\PlatformData\\CameraCapture-[GUID].jpg.jpg"
  FileSize    789355
  Flash   No
  FNumber 0.0
  GpsLatitude {double[3]}
  GpsLatitudeRef  Unknown
  GpsLongitude    {double[3]}
  GpsLongitudeRef Unknown
  Height  1944
  IsColor true
  IsValid true
  LoadTime    {00:00:00.1340000}
  Make    "HTC"
  Model   "7 Trophy"
  Orientation TopRight
  ResolutionUnit  Inch
  Software    "Windows Phone 7.5"
  ThumbnailData   {byte[14913]}
  ThumbnailOffset 518
  ThumbnailSize   14913
  UserComment null
  Width   2592
  XResolution 72.0
  YResolution 72.0
  ```

Looks like doing something with the EXIF every 200ms is *not* the cause. Out of curiosity I had a second look at the EXIF data after synching the pictures with the PC. The values are just not there. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot Heinrich, that helped to clear up a lot of confusion.  Do you think Windows Phone 7 does not save the exif data correctly? I downloaded a sample pic from the and checked it on my pc. It had all the exif tags I needed. Here is the url                         http://www.mobiletechworld.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/WP_000272-3-Large.jpg   Please check that and post back your comments. Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: P.S. I need to get 3 values, namely ISO, Exposure Time and F.Stop number. You can find that the linked image, taken with a windows phone has all the required attributes. I just need a way to read these! :)

Comment: I see, the image behind your link has all the tags set. Well, either they "enhanced" them by purpose or the functionality depends on vendor and/or model and/or firmware. Mine is a HTC Trophy running Mango. Yours? It would be nice if other people tested this with their cameras and posted the result.

Comment: I don't yet have a Windows phone, hence I am relying on good people like to you to help me out. :) I don't think they have enhanced the pics in any way. You can visit http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2011/07/08/htc-sensation-camera-samples-photos-and-1080p-video/ for the original blog post. Now, just supposing the tags, including ISO are set. Is there any way I can read them? I did a lot of work on this and am still not able to find any solution. :(