# How to Get Geolocation Information from Pictures

Tags: windows-phone-8, geolocation, exif

How would it be possible to get geolocation information from images captured with the default camera in Windows Phone? Is this data recorded when an image is captured, or is this something I have to implement myself?

Answer (score 2):

Like most phone cameras, Windows Phone allows the user to select whether latitude and longitude (Geolocation) are recorded when taking a photo. Presumably, this is for privacy reasons. See details of how to enable/disable here: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/pictures/add-location-info-to-my-pictures

```
Start > App list > Settings
Then: Applications > Pictures+camera.
Then: Turn on Include location info in pictures you take.
```

This data is stored in the image as EXIF properties at the time that the image is saved by the device - you don't need to do this yourself (however you might need to set the properties programmatically to do this if you're writing a program that captures images). See this post for an example of how to access it: [Get EXIF tags in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969063/get-exif-tags-in-windows-phone-7) and [How to Fetch the Geotag details of the captured image or stored image in Windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801314/how-to-fetch-the-geotag-details-of-the-captured-image-or-stored-image-in-windows)

The data points of interest are: `GpsLatitude` and `GpsLongitude`.